# Trouble to outsource http get request into a function - error "not a function"

Tags: node.js, function, http

I want to write code for a server but outsource http get routines to a separate .js file. When I try to call the function within the server.js file I get the error "not a function"

To check my general setup I created a dummy function which I call within server.js. This appears to work fine

Server.js:

```
const http = require("http");
const MSWratings = require('./MSWratings.js');

MSWratings.Ratings();
MSWratings.TestFunction();
```

MSWratings.js:

```
//Load HTTP module
const http = require("http");


const TestFunction = function () {
  console.log('test function');
}

const Ratings = function () {
http.get('XXX', (res) => {
  const { statusCode } = res;
  const contentType = res.headers['content-type'];

  let error;
  if (statusCode !== 200) {
    error = new Error('Request Failed.\n' +
                      `Status Code: ${statusCode}`);
  } else if (!/^application\/json/.test(contentType)) {
    error = new Error('Invalid content-type.\n' +
                      `Expected application/json but received ${contentType}`);
  }
  if (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    // consume response data to free up memory
    res.resume();
    return;
  }

  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  let rawData = '';
  res.on('data', (chunk) => { rawData += chunk; });
  res.on('end', () => {
    try {
      const parsedData = JSON.parse(rawData);
      console.log(parsedData[0].solidRating);
      //console.log(parsedData);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e.message);
    }
  });
}).on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(`Got error: ${e.message}`);
});

}

module.exports = {Ratings};
module.exports = {TestFunction};
```

The get request does not run, I get the error 
TypeError: MSWratings.Ratings is not a function
instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting your exports the second time you assign to it.

Try

```
module.exports = {Ratings, TestFunction};
```

Comment: Thanks :)
Solved my problem